# @SuppressWarnings - Static Variable

Tags: java

Which parameter **@SuppressWarnings** use to hide **Warning(209.56): static variable Should be qualified by type name, javax.swing.ListSelectionModel, instead of by an expression**?

Comment: Why don't you just fix your code?

Comment: The advice from the warning is right. Listen to it instead of suppressing.

Comment: Above comments are not constructive, do not contribute to answering the question, and only serve to further alienate new users.

Comment: @Jeff - I think the above comments are appropriate (if perhaps a little blunt)

Comment: indeed they are. There are few really valid uses for @SuppressWarnings, most having to do with being required to use code structures that cause warnings because of a reliance on outdated libraries (usually this means suppressing specific deprecation warnings).

Comment: I think Jeff is right. Alot of times I really dont care what the compiler thinks. I am the master, not the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

This one:

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
```

And to nay-sayers, yes ideally the code would be fixed. But in the real world, sadly that isn't always possible. Besides, it's not what @user941059 asked for.

Comment: If it isn't possible to fix the actual problem, then most likely it isn't possible to add the `SuppressWarnings` either.

Comment: indeed. It's (certainly in this case) no more work to properly qualify the classname than it is to add the suppression.

Comment: True. In this case. But what about a project working with 10 other developers all editing the same 3000 line file? Manually merging the code changes in, you could just about cope with a single annotation added at class level. But merge conflicts across 3000 lines would be a bit trickier. Again, I'm not defending this style of working, just pointing out that, sadly, it happens.